# What is the latest stable version of cakephp 3.x?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

Which one is the stable version of CakePhp ?
CakePhp 2.6.x or CakePhp 3.x

Comment: Both. They still release both by the look of it. Anything release and not RC, alpha or beta can be seen as stable. just look at their site.

Comment: Those who can read have a clear advantage: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases

Comment: cakephp.org has the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP 3.0.4 Released

PUBLISHED ON MAY 7, 2015 12:00 AM

CakePHP 3.0.4 Released The CakePHP core team is happy to announce the immediate availability of CakePHP 3.0.4

Answer (score 1):

The repository with all CakePHP versions is on GitHub https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/

when you click on "Branch: master" you can look up all branches, which usually are under active development (the so called trunk, they could be unstable or may have unfinished features and therefore should not be used in production).

[image]

When you click on "Tags" in the opened "Branch: master" tab you can see all versions - these are the release candidates, beta-, alpha- and production ready versions of the software.

[image]

For example, when you look for the most recent version of the 2.x branch search for the highest tag number beginning with 2.*, today it happens to be 2.7.3 https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.7.3

You can download this particular version by clicking on "Download ZIP" or checking it out via GIT

```
git clone --branch <tag_name> <repo_url>
```